# XPages Repeat control: variable not found

Tags: custom-controls, xpages, repeater

I have a Custom Control with with 4 repeat controls. One of the repeat controls is nested inside another, so it's much like this:

```
<repeat...> 
</repeat...>
<repeat... var="row" value="calculations...">
    <repeat... var="cell" value="more calculations...">
        <field label="cell.label">
        </field>
    </repeat...>
</repeat...>
<repeat...>
</repeat...>
```

Now, if I use repeatControls=false, it almost works except that I get "cell not found" when partially refreshing the entire control. When I use repeatControls=true, the calculations above happen AFTER the load of the repeats, so nothing is displayed. And I have to be able to do a partial refresh of the entire control if needed.

How can I address this limitation? Where is that variable 'cell'? Why cannot XPages find it?

Thanks for your great help!

**Update**

The error also occurs when saving the document. The document is opened, a button is used to place it in edit-mode, a field is changed and then the save-button is clicked. Somehow, the repeat-var is 'not found'.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen with nested repeat controls in the ApplyRequestValues phase of a partial refresh. It might be worth confirming if that's what you're encountering here.

One way to check is to use XPages OpenLog Logger with a custom error page. That will capture a stack trace which will include the phase the error first occurs in. The lines that start "com.sun.faces.lifecycle" are the ones that pinpoint the current phase.

If so, this is the solution I use http://www.intec.co.uk/dataviews-and-nested-repeats/

Comment: It took me a while to set it up, but the Phase listener works. I found out that during phase 2 (?) the repeat-var cannot be found. So in the repeat itself, I set the value-property to null based on if(requestScope.currPhase==2). The page runs without errors, but now the values of the fields are not saved... If that's the Apply Request Values, how can it be that the repeat-var is absent??

Comment: I haven't investigated it fully, because I've only used read only components. But my theory is that it's to do with repeatControls="false" (the default) on the outer repeat. If that's the case, the component tree will only have one instance of each component in the repeat - effectively one row not bound to any data. Based on that, during the earlier phases of the lifecycle, the value bindings for the inner repeat won't be able to be resolved. That certainly sounds plausible. If my theory is correct, setting repeatControls="true" on the outer repeat (and possibly the inner too) will work.

Comment: Of course, if you set repeatControls="true", it loads a set of components for each row displayed, at page load time. That means you can't use a pager, because the number and binding of the controls can't be modified. If you need something like that, reloading the page and using a sessionScope variable to determine the start for the repeat contents should work.